# Python referencing static methods within a class - best practise

Tags: python, static-methods

This is just an "Is there a better way of doing x?" question about @staticmethod functions in classes using python.

I have the following:

```
class my_class():
    @staticmethod
    def function_a():
        print("hello")

    @staticmethod
    def function_b():
        my_class.function_a()
```

Obviously with static classes you have no "self" reference, but is there another way to reference functions inside a class without using the class name "my_class.xxxxx"?

Most other languages have a different version, for example php has `$this->` for inheritance and `self::` for static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_class.function_b` should be a [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
@classmethod
def function_b(cls):
    cls.function_a()
```

classmethods get passed a reference to the class that they are called on (or the class of the instance that they are called on) as the first argument rather than the usual `self`.

Comment: So you cant reference any other way with static methods, you can only reference with the full class name? And class methods are the best way to do a staticmethod when you dont want to reference the classname? (just want to make sure its the best and only option)

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  But, with python, there are no hidden variables that just happen to be there (e.g. implicit `this`, or `arguments` or ...).  With python, the namespace consists of the enclosing namespace (e.g. stuff picked up via closure) and the stuff passed into the function + locals that the function defines itself.  If you want to reference other methods on the class, (without naming the class explicitly) you need a classmethod or an instance method.  You can't do it from a staticmethod.